# How fast or lightweight Is Protocol Buffer?

Tags: c#, remoting, protocol-buffers

Is Protocol Buffer for .NET gonna be lightweight/faster than Remoting(the SerializationFormat.Binary)?  Will there be a first class support for it in language/framework terms? i.e. is it handled transparently like with Remoting/WebServices?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I very much doubt that it will ever have direct language support or even framework support - it's the kind of thing which is handled perfectly well with 3rd party libraries.

[My own port of the Java code](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) is explicit - you have to call methods to serialize/deserialize. (There are RPC stubs which will automatically serialize/deserialize, but no RPC implementation yet.)

[Marc Gravell's project](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) fits in very nicely with WCF though - as far as I'm aware, you just need to tell it (once) to use protocol buffers for serialization, and the rest is transparent.

In terms of speed, you should look at [Marc Gravell's benchmark page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance). My code tends to be slightly faster than his, but both are much, much faster than the other serialization/deserialization options in the framework. It should be pointed out that protocol buffers are much more limited as well - they don't try to serialize arbitrary types, only the supported ones. We're going to try to support more of the common data types (decimal, DateTime etc) in a portable way (as their own protocol buffer messages) in future.

Answer (score 37):

Some performance and size metrics are on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance). I haven't got Jon's stats on there at the moment, just because the page is a little old (Jon: we must fix that!).

Re being transparent; [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) can hook into WCF via the contract; note that it plays nicely with MTOM over basic-http too. This doesn't work with Silverlight, though, since Silverlight lacks the injection point. If you use svcutil, you also need to add an attribute to class (via a partial class).

Re BinaryFormatter (remoting); yes, this has full supprt; you can do this simply by a trivial `ISerializable` implementation (i.e. just call the `Serializer` method with the same args). If you use `protogen` to create your classes, then it can do it for you: you can enable this at the command line via arguments (it isn't enabled by default as `BinaryFormatter` doesn't work on all frameworks [CF, etc]).

Note that for very small objects (single instances, etc) on local remoting (IPC), the raw `BinaryFormatter` performance is actually better - but for non-trivial graphs or remote links (network remoting) protobuf-net can out-perform it pretty well.

I should also note that the protocol buffers wire format doesn't directly support inheritance; protobuf-net can spoof this (while retaining wire-compatibility), but like with XmlSerializer, you need to declare the sub-classes up-front.

---

### Why are there two versions?

The joys of open source, I guess ;-p Jon and I have worked on joint projects before, and have discussed merging these two, but the fact is that they target two different scenarios:

- [dotnet-protobufs](http://github.com/jskeet/dotnet-protobufs/tree/master) (Jon's) is a port of the existing java version. This means it has a very familiar API for anybody already using the java version, and it is built on typical java constructs (builder classes, immutable data classes, etc) - with a few C# twists.
- [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) (Marc's) is a ground-up re-implementation following the same binary format (indeed, a critical requirement is that you can interchange data between different formats), but using typical .NET idioms:

  - mutable data classes (no builders)
  - the serialization member specifics are expressed in attributes (comparable to `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, etc)

If you are working on java and .NET clients, Jon's is probably a good choice for the familiar API on both sides. If you are pure .NET, protobuf-net has advantages - the familiar .NET style API, but also:

- you aren't *forced* to be contract-first (although you can, and a code-generator is supplied)
- you can re-use your existing objects (in fact, `[DataContract]` and `[XmlType]` classes can often be used without any changes at all)
- it has full support for inheritance (which it achieves on the wire by spoofing encapsulation) (possibly unique for a protocol buffers implementation? note that sub-classes have to be declared in advance)
- it goes out of its way to plug into and exploit core .NET tools (`BinaryFormatter`, `XmlSerializer`, WCF, `DataContractSerializer`) - allowing it to work directly as a remoting engine. This would presumably be quite a big split from the main java trunk for Jon's port.

Re merging them; I think we'd both be open to it, but it seems unlikely you'd want both feature sets, since they target such different requirements.